# PHP include from many subfolders

Tags: php

Dears,

I am at very pressed situation :-(

I started to learn Javascript some months ago and I have written some pages for amusements of my invalid niece to her birthday this Friday. Separate pages are OK. But I feel calamitous that I am still unable to set php including. I have two earlier websites with php code that runs very well so I used to copy the code from those to my new index.php. Of course, I changed the name of folder and names of files. My two websites have menu and submenus, my new website has only menu without submenu, but every file has its own folder.
I quickly translated it to English and made it shorter but principle is the same. I tried:

```
<?php
$x = isset($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : 'hello';  

if (isset($x) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/', $x))  {
    if (file_exists ("../pokus/".$x.".php"))  {
        include "../pokus/".$x.".php"; 
    } else {
        include (__DIR__)."/404.php";
    }
}
?>
```

but allegedly the files "was not found on this server." Naturally, they are all of them uploaded to my server.

My HTML code:

```
<ul> 
    <li>
        <a href="/hello/"<?php echo $x == "hello" ? 'class="choice"' : '';?>>
            <img src = "pictures/hello.jpg" width = "320" height = "240"> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/folder1/file1/" <?php echo $x == '../file1' ? 'class="choice"' : '';?>>
            <img src = "pictures/pict1-menu.jpg" width = "320" height = "240">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/folder2/file2/" <?php echo $x == '../file2' ? 'class="choice"' : '';?>>
            <img src = "pictures/pict2-menu.jpg" width = "320" height = "240">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/folder3/file3/" <?php echo $x == '../file3' ? 'class="choice"' : '';?>>
            <img src = "pictures/pict3-menu.jpg" width = "320" height = "240">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

At folder called pokus I have index.php and hello.php (= some sentences to her birthday). Then I have subfolder folder1 and file1.php inside, subfolder folder2 and file2.php inside etc. I am forced to use many subfolders because each subfolder contains many pictures A1.jpg, A2.jpg ... D4.jpg using JS FOR cycle and therefore it is unable to mix them together.

I am very astonished that not even file hello.php sitting beside index.php I am not able to load. My Apache says that this file "was not found on this server." But the file hello.php is loaded immediately with opening index.php! Why is Apache so paranoid?

Here is live illustration: http://pokus.zlatberry.cz/

Can anyone devote your time to help me, please? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone include can be written like `include ('file.php');` or `include 'file.php';` So both work.

Comment: I would recommend using the `composer` autoloader rather than trying to create your own. Here is a [link](https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer) with explanation.

Comment: @EternalHour it's very unlikely OP is dealing with classes here...

Comment: @Joan : Something I have realized when programming : if it's too complicated or complex it means the logic must be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I have realized when programming : if it's too complicated or complex it means the logic must be changed. I suggest organizing your chaos so that it's easier to debug.

Try this for file exists :

```
$filename = "../pokus/".$x.".php";

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    include ($filename);
} else {
    include (__DIR__)."/404.php";
}
```

Other than this, try break your codes in small chunks. Lots of ternary operators. Are they necessary? If all your files are present in said folders, the program is sending you a 404 because it is not understanding your logic. I'd say for the sake of debugging try with a different logic. Go back to the basics. Simplicity often works well.

Example :

```
if(isset($_GET['x'])){
 $x = $_GET['x'];
}...etc.
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but I get undefined variable if I have not set  "default" page hello.php

Comment: Two hours ago I realized that I have not no .htaccess file! That is the big problem I think. I set RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?$ ?x=$1&y=$2 [L,QSA]  but it is for dvo variables and I have only one. (I am sorry I do not know how to paste the whole code...)

Comment: @Joan : Hmm... Now if you have to involve .htaccess in this, it gets complicated. You can achieve what you want with PHP by following a different logic. For example, in your `index.php` you can include_once `'hello.php'` then set up some links `<a href="index.php?game1">Select game 1</a>`. Then you can use `if(isset($_GET))` to show your pages based on the variables in the url.

Comment: Now I think that the best advice was to make it easier :-) Thanks to Marie-Eva BB Volmar. So I put all php files into the root directory altogether and on the contrary I changed adresses of img.src to ../folder-of-images/A1.jpg and so on. And - it works as I wanted, hurrah

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are having the folder names which is good but your links are to hello and not to hello.php

If you give the php extension it does show the file properly.